# Add fourth box to dynamic drop drop

Tags: javascript

As you can see from my code, I have taken it from another site.

I would like to add a fourth drop down to the page. It needs to the be first drop down. The type drop down.

The code I have only allows 3 dynamic drop downs, it is basically a state, city and country drop down that I have ammended to suit my needs.

I have added it to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9keepxw/2/)

```
<tr>
    <td width="254" style="text-align: left;">
      <p>
        Type:
        <select name="Type" id="Type">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
          <option value="Annually">Annually</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <tr>
      <td width="254" style="text-align: left;">
        Box:
        <select name="country" id="country" onchange="setStates();">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Sky HD">Sky HD</option>
          <option value="Sky+">Sky+</option>
          <option value="Sky Standard">Sky Standard</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="252" style="text-align: left;">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;">
    Product :
    <select name="state" id="state" onchange="setCities();">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: left;">
    <p>&nbsp; </p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: left;">
    Price :  
    <select name="city" type="text" id="city" />
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: left;">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
```

The Javascript code

```
/* This script and many more are available free online at
The JavaScript Source!! http://www.javascriptsource.com
Created by: Michael J. Damato | http://developing.damato.net/ */
// State lists
var states = new Array();

states['Sky HD'] = new Array('Platinum', 'Gold', 'Diamond');
states['Sky+'] = new Array('Platinum', 'Gold', 'Diamond');
states['Sky Standard'] = new Array('Platinum', 'Gold', 'Diamond');

// City lists
var cities = new Array();

cities['Sky HD'] = new Array();
cities['Sky HD']['Platinum']          = new Array('£8.49');
cities['Sky HD']['Gold']          = new Array('£7.49');
cities['Sky HD']['Diamond']          = new Array('£6.49');

cities['Sky+'] = new Array();
cities['Sky+']['Platinum']          = new Array('£8.49');
cities['Sky+']['Gold']          = new Array('£7.49');
cities['Sky+']['Diamond']          = new Array('£6.49');

cities['Sky Standard'] = new Array();
cities['Sky Standard']['Platinum']          = new Array('£8.49');
cities['Sky Standard']['Gold']          = new Array('£7.49');
cities['Sky Standard']['Diamond']          = new Array('£6.49');

function setStates() {
  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateList = states[cntrySel.value];
  changeSelect('state', stateList, stateList);
  setCities();
}

function setCities() {
  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateSel = document.getElementById('state');
  cityList = cities[cntrySel.value][stateSel.value];
  changeSelect('city', cityList, cityList);
}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;
  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }
}

// Multiple onload function created by: Simon Willison
// http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  setStates();
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Need to add a fourth drop down box, if the user selects Annually the page will show different prices (£89.99, £79.99 for example) At the moment the page is only showing monthly prices

Comment: Unrelated suggestion, you are creating `Array`s but are not using `Array` functionality, you really meant to make `cities` and `states` be of type `Object` (and their inner objects which have keys that are not integers). Most developers would prefer to see the literal forms of `Array` and `Object`: `[1,2,3]` and `{a:1,b:2:3}`. In PHP everything is an array, in JS Array and Object are not the same thing

Comment: Should there ever be a scenario where, given type, box and product, the user can select from more than once price? Sounds to me like you only need three levels of dropdowns, but should be using a different means of displaying the resulting price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script that this is based on is not ideal if I understand your data model correctly. Besides what is mentioned in comments, the State / City scenario has a hierarchy to it, that does not seem applicable to your use case. The list of products appears to be identical regardless of which box I choose, correct? And the combination yields a unique price?

If so, the script you're starting with differs from your desired result in at least two ways:

- There is no point in updating the other dropdowns, when another dropdown changes
- You should never be able to select the price at all, so this doesn't need to be a dropdown.

I would begin by defining a readable data source, of all the options and their resulting prices:

```
var prices = [
    { type: 'monthly', box: 'Sky HD', product: 'Platinum', price: '$ 10' },
    { type: 'monthly', box: 'Sky HD', product: 'Gold', price: '$ 20' },
    { type: 'monthly', box: 'Sky HD', product: 'Diamond', price: '$ 30' },
    { type: 'monthly', box: 'Sky+', product: 'Platinum', price: '$ 40' },
    ...
];
```

After that, define the different filters. For each filtered property, I'll assume there exists a `select` with a corresponding `class`.

```
var options = ['type','box','product'];
```

With that taken care of, iterate over the options, find the unique values for that option in the data source and populate the dropdowns. Also, add an on change listener to each dropdown.

```
options.forEach(function(opt) {
    var drop = document.querySelector('.'+opt);
    var unique = Object.keys(prices.reduce(function(x,y) { return x[y[opt]] = 1, x; }, {}));
    unique.forEach(function(value) {
        var htmlOption = document.createElement('option');
        htmlOption.value = htmlOption.innerText = value;
        drop.options.add(htmlOption);
    });

    drop.onchange = function() {
        updatePrice();
    };
});
```

All that remains is to define `updatePrice`, which is called each time any of the dropdowns are changed. We iterate through all properties again, and filter out only the prices that match the current selection. If your data source is set up correctly, that should leave you with exactly one match. You could of course add error handling to this to verify that:

```
function updatePrice() {
    var matches = prices;
    options.forEach(function(opt) {
        var drop = document.querySelector('.'+opt);
        matches = matches.filter(function(price) { return price[opt] == drop.value; });
    });
    document.querySelector('.price').innerText = matches[0].price;
};
```

Done. Call `updatePrice` once to set up the initial value:

```
updatePrice();
```

This is assuming your scripts are placed last in `body`. If they're in head, you need to defer the call to `updatePrice`, and also the setting up of the dropdowns, until DOMReady.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u60wbxLk/)

**Update:** For IE8 compatibility, convenience functions `Array.prototype.forEach` has been rewritten as regular for loops; `Array.prototype.reduce`, `Array.prototype.filter` and `Object.prototype.keys` has been replaced with functions that roughly mimics their behavior.

[IE8-updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpq98qxr/1/)

Comment: WOW! Thanks David, looks perfect to me. Thank you so much. Can I ask one thing, can the price go into an input box? I need to submit the data into a database

Comment: I've changed price to select class and showing in a drop down box. Struggling to get it to work on my page at the moment. Have copied the code to a new page. Not showing any options at the moment

Comment: I have added the javascript in the head and the html in the body.

Comment: @padders01: Oh, but you absolutely need to have the same logic serverside, you can't just accept whatever you receive from the client to be the price. Even if you set the price to a readonly or hidden field, the user can easily manipulate that. You can trust `type`, `box` and `product` to be accurate, because the user can manipulate them anyway, but the price you must calculate on the server as well.

Comment: @padders01: My code above is assuming that the script is in the bottom of `body`. If you want it in head you need to make sure that at least the `options.forEach(...);` block and the final `updatePrice();` call are made in an `onLoad` event.

Comment: I am struggling to make it work with the javascript in the head. Can you help? Sorry

Comment: @padders01: [Updated fiddle with script in head here](http://jsfiddle.net/hx4jwa5p/). Note the `onload` attribute in `body`, and the `setupOnLoad` function in the script.

Comment: thank you so much for this. I am looking at getting it to work. I am struggling at the moment. No idea why. I have used javascript for a few years now. I will keep working at it

Comment: Does all the javascript code need to be in one wrap in the head?

Comment: @padders01: Not sure what you mean with a wrap, but all code that accesses elements in the document (for example the `options.forEach` block since it updates actual dropdowns) has to be executed after the document is loaded. You can't run that code immediately in head, since the elements don't exist at that point. If you place the code in head, that code must be in a function that is called on page load. I have added a fiddle with a working example of that in my previous comment.

Comment: I am really not sure what I am doing wrong, sorry. I have copied all the code from the webpage and pasted into the link below

http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3835

Comment: @padders01: Your code is working for me. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: There are no options in the drop down menus, nothing there

Comment: hostcode.sourceforge.net isn't working for me (the compile & execute part). I copied your code entirely into JSBin ([here](http://jsbin.com/qekuvohixo/edit?html,output)). Are you seeing the same problem there?

Comment: Right, I have just tried it in Chrome and it works fine. Not working in IE8. Do you know why this would happen? I need it to work in IE8, the work computer only have XP and IE8

Comment: Googling it obect.keys doesn't work in IE8. Any ideas?

Comment: @padders01: [Here is a polyfill for Object.keys](https://coderwall.com/p/q8qacw/object-keys-polyfill). This code utilizes several features of the Array prototype which won't work in IE8 either, such as `forEach`, `filter` and `reduce`. These can all be rewritten as regular for loops with conditions, etc. If you want tidier code, though, I really recommend [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim), which will allow you to use all of these features in IE8 (and the `Object.keys` polyfill will be redundant if you use es5-shim).

Comment: Thanks again David. Really appreciate your time helping me. Not sure where to go with that es5-shim but I will have a look at it

Comment: A polyfill adds language features that are not natively supported by the browser. If `.reduce` does not exist on an array, for instance, an `Array.prototype.reduce` polyfill defines that function and mimics the behavior of the standard function. Es5-shim is a collection of polyfills, it tries to make as many EcmaScript5 features as possible available in browsers that are not ES5 compliant, and it does a good job of it, too. So all you have to do is include the es5-shim script file before your other scripts, and you will be able to use `Object.keys` etc, even where it isn't natively supported.

Comment: I've added the es5-shim.js to my page and it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: @padders01: Turns out `add` isn't available on `HTMLSelectElement` either. Change `drop.add` to `drop.options.add` in the code. Sorry, it's been a while since I last spent time supporting old browsers. With that change, everything works when I emulate IE8 locally. I can't show it in JSBin, because JSBin doesn't appear to work in IE8 either.

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work. You don't need to apologise

I have added it to sourceforge just to show you what I have done

Added the es5shim at the top and changed drop.add to drop.options.add

http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3838

Comment: Hm. Two things: apparently `drop.options.add` doesn't work the way I thought it did, either. I thought I tried it, but now I can't reproduce. `drop.options.add(new Option(value, value))` is what works. Second, Github is not a CDN. They're picky about that, and you won't be able to hotlink the resource from them because of how they set mime types. The github link is for downloading if you want to distribute it yourself, but if you want a CDN, ES5-shim is available on cloudflare: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.3.1/es5-shim.min.js

Comment: Hi David, still not working

function setupOnLoad() {
    options.forEach(function(opt) {
        var drop = document.querySelector('.'+opt);
        var unique = Object.keys(prices.reduce(function(x,y) { return x[y[opt]] = 1, x; }, {}));
        unique.forEach(function(value) {
            var htmlOption = document.createElement('option');
            htmlOption.value = htmlOption.innerText = value;
            drop.options.add(htmlOption)        });

        drop.onchange = function() {
            updatePrice();
        };
    });

Comment: I host the ES5-shim myself, just for speed I used the hotlink. i have changed it to the one you linked to

Comment: @padders01: I can't see that you've changed the code according to my last comment?

Comment: Must have copied the old code

function setupOnLoad() {
    options.forEach(function(opt) {
        var drop = document.querySelector('.'+opt);
        var unique = Object.keys(prices.reduce(function(x,y) { return x[y[opt]] = 1, x; }, {}));
        unique.forEach(function(value) {
            var htmlOption = document.createElement('option');
            htmlOption.value = htmlOption.innerText = value;
           drop.options.add(new Option(value, value))       });

        drop.onchange = function() {
            updatePrice();
        };
    });

Comment: [This exact document](http://pastebin.com/buBpd7YQ) works for me when I emulate IE8. If it doesn't for you, your problems may be elsewhere. Please provide an error message if you have further issues. If it helps, you may skip es5-shim and use the `Object.keys` polyfill from above, and rewrite the array functions into for loops of your own. Remove code, see which parts work and what fails.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Copied that code into new document and still doesn't work. Nothing in the drop down menus. The error in IE is Line 37 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: That's `unique.forEach`, one of the functions that has to be polyfilled. Check the console to see that ES5-shim has been loaded. Your browser may be blocking external sources on local documents. [I uploaded the document here](http://www.davidhedlund.se/dropdowns.htm) if running scripts locally is the culprit.

Comment: So that link you sent me still doesn't work on IE8. Works fine from Chrome. Not sure there is a problem with IE opening the external source. When i put the link into IE it open the javascript file. This is very strange and getting more and more frustrating

Comment: @padders01: That's weird, it works when I emulate IE8, but I guess that's not exactly the same thing. I don't have access to IE8, but see my updated answer. I rewrote the code to not use any functions that es5-shim should be needed for. If any of those were the culprit, it might work better now (not the document I linked to, but the new fiddle in my answer).

Comment: Not worked again, doesn't work in Chrome either.

Added Sourceforge to show how I have entered code onto my page, incase I am doing anything wrong

http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3897

Comment: @padders01: My bad, I wasn't working from the version with script in head. [Updated again, here](http://jsfiddle.net/kpq98qxr/1/)

Comment: That works in Chrome now but still not in IE8. Error on line 35. Object doesn't support this propety or method again

Comment: When running IE8 with Compatibility view (which was defaulted for Intranet sites) it stops it working.Not sure why but it did. I have turn off Compatibility view and now the drop down menus working fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can I ask for one more favour? Is it possible to have the price in a input text box? I have tried but it didn't populate

Comment: Hah! Well that explains a lot. I was running IE11, emulating IE8 without being able to reproduce your errors, but *you* were running IE8 emulating IE7 (which is what compatibility view does). Don't use compatibility view, it's terrible. If you turn that off, I'm guessing my old links will work as well. If you want the price in a textbox, the only change to the script is that you shouldn't set the `innerText` property but the `value`. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwjbrwj7/). But then I must reiterate that you should never trust the price you receive from the cilent, validate serverside.

Comment: You SIr, are a legend. I can't thank you enough for your help. It's been a week now I think? If i could buy you a drink I would (that's if you drink).

Comment: I can't give you +1 feedback as my reputation is only 14

Comment: Just glad to hear it worked out in the end! I have more +1's than I can count already.